# How to test linear restriction with both intercept and slope

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

I have estimated the model

$y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x + u$

I want to test the restriction that $\beta_{0} = 3$ and that $\beta_{1} = -2$. after setting both betas to their hypothesized values and rearranging, I get the equation:

$z = u$ where $z = y + 2x -3$

now I am lost as to how to actually run this regression because there are no independent variable and no intercept as well. if the value for the intercept was not restricted then i would simply define a new variable as $y + 2x$ and just compute it's ssr and use it to compute an F-statistics.

Comment: This is a one-liner in `R`: `anova(lm(y ~ x), {y <- y - (3 + -2*x); lm(y ~ 0)})`.  There's a trick involved: you have to fool `anova` into believing you used the same response variable in both models--you can't give them different names (like `y` and `y.1`, say).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, This seems to give me that answer I need.  correct me if I'm wrong but the ssr for lm(y~0)  is just the sum of squares of the new y right? what does lm(y~0) actually compute?

Comment: `lm(y ~ 0)` basically asks `lm` to treat `y` as if it were the residuals (which it is, relative to your null model) and perform its standard calculations.  It doesn't do any fitting (which it cheerfully tells you when you apply `print` or `summary` to its output).

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the sum of squared errors (or the likelihood in, say, a logistic regression case) and then conduct an $F$-test.  You'll probably have to do it manually.
$$
F = \frac{ \frac{SS_{resid,restricted}-SS_{resid,full}}{df_{resid,restricted}-df_{resid,full}}}
{\frac{SS_{resid,full}}{df_{resid,full}}}
$$